# Get list of deleted items between two dates using REST

Tags: list, document-library

is there a way to get the list of all deleted items between two dates using REST services in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

With rest - no, but you can get deleted item with Client Object Model (`Web.GetChanges`) or with SiteData.svc (`GetChanges` method)

Comment: Thanks, can you give me more details?